# How to set the requested configurations from scratch to run spark on yarn?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hpc

I am newbie to running spark on yarn and I have tried it on an HPC cluster. Since I could not figure out how to set the configurations properly, I can't connect to yarn successfully and my logs are as below:

```
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/11/22 18:35:59 INFO SparkContext: Running Spark version 1.4.1
16/11/22 18:36:00 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/11/22 18:36:00 WARN SparkConf: In Spark 1.0 and later spark.local.dir will be overridden by the value set by the cluster manager (via SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS in mesos/standalone and LOCAL_DIRS in YARN).
16/11/22 18:36:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to:  
16/11/22 18:36:00 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to:  
16/11/22 18:36:00 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set( ); users with modify permissions: Set( )
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriver@172.23.9.106:35138]
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkDriver' on port 35138.
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO SparkEnv: Registering MapOutputTracker
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO SparkEnv: Registering BlockManagerMaster
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /local/tmp/spark-c335cd9f-7719-4ffd-942c-2bbcc543e3c8/blockmgr-2057f8aa-e074-4910-a1fa-3fc9c73ad1f1
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 16.6 GB
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO HttpFileServer: HTTP File server directory is /local/tmp/spark-c335cd9f-7719-4ffd-942c-2bbcc543e3c8/httpd-63876231-4681-4e75-bfd9-f46edf02087c
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO HttpServer: Starting HTTP Server
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'HTTP file server' on port 46754.
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO SparkEnv: Registering OutputCommitCoordinator
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO Utils: Successfully started service 'SparkUI' on port 4040.
16/11/22 18:36:01 INFO SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://172.23.9.106:4040
16/11/22 18:36:02 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR file:/hard-mounts/user/311/ /cosine-lsh.jar at http://172.23.9.106:46754/jars/cosine-lsh.jar with timestamp 1479836162928
16/11/22 18:36:03 INFO RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
16/11/22 18:36:04 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/11/22 18:36:05 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/11/22 18:36:06 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 2 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/11/22 18:36:07 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 3 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/11/22 18:36:08 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 4 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/11/22 18:36:09 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 5 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/11/22 18:36:10 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 6 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/11/22 18:36:11 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 7 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
16/11/22 18:36:12 INFO Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:8032. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

I use spark 1.4.1 and I have downloaded Hadoop 2.6 to my local folder in the cluster. Here is my spark configuration lines in my app code:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("LSH-Cosine")
      .setMaster("yarn-client") //local[*]
      .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0")
      .set("spark.local.dir", "/local/tmp");
```

And I run my code through the jar file via the bash file as below:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

#PBS -l walltime=00:45:00

module load Spark/1.4.1
module load Hadoop

cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR

export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/vsc-hard-mounts/user/311/31182/hadoop-2.6.0-src/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/conf

spark-submit \
  --class com.soundcloud.lsh.MainCerebro \
  --master yarn-client \
  --num-executors 50 \
  --driver-memory 32g \
  --executor-memory 32g \
  --executor-cores 2 \
  cosine-lsh.jar
```

I tried to designate HADOOP_CONF_DIR to the conf folder found in hadoop 2.6 which I have downloaded to my local folder. In addition, I changed yarn-site.xml as

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

I have wrapped up all the trials above from the related stackoverflow posts. Since many of them have no a clear answer, I want to post this question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have hadoop daemons running? It seems like your spark can't connect to resource manager.